# Why am I getting extra commits in my pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Here is my git workflow:

1. I create a feature branch from production.
2. Hopefully hours go by (not days) as I make changes to feature branch.
3. When I'm done...
4. If days have gone by, I stash my changes.
5. I'll do a `git rebase origin master` to pull latest into feature branch.
6. I'll, then, `git stash apply` to get my changes back.
7. I do a commit and then push the changes
8. Then I create a PR to staging

When I create a Pull Request to staging from my feature branch, for some reason the PR will include other commits that aren't mine.

Question 1: Does the workflow above look normal?
Question 2: Why am I getting extra commits in my PR to staging?

Comment: Are you rebasing from staging to production as well, or just merging?

Comment: Do you mean when I'm in the staging branch, am I doing `git rebase origin master`? If so, no.

Comment: Does the extra commits that are included in your pull request also include changes to files your pull request wasn't supposed to change? Or are *only* your changes included, it's just extra *commits* that you see?

Comment: The former case.

Comment: Then @dunni's answer is likely the right one, someone else is merging to master without going through staging. There's therefore commits on master that isn't in staging, so when you base your branch on master, and then create a pull request towards staging, *all* commits from master not currently on staging will be included. Go talk to the person that made those commits and see if they are following the guidelines.

Comment: Is it possible to just create a PR with just my changes?

Comment: You can do that if you directly merge production to staging before creating your PR for your feature branch. Then you see only the changes from your feature branch.

Answer (score 2):

1. Stashing and reapply after rebasing should not be necessary. Instead, at point 4 you just should do a regular commit. After that you can rebase your commits.
2. That means, that somebody else is circumventing the process and merging changes to production without going through staging first. It could also be, that when the merge to production happens, actually a squash merge or another operation, which changes the history, is used, which would mean that on a commit level staging and production would be different (not necessarily on content side).